# Using yalc with Vue results in unknown element

Tags: vue.js

I am using a third party component (vue-image-lightbox) which currently has a bug.  I cloned the repo and made the change and want to deploy it with my app to see if it fixes the issue.  To do this I installed yalc.

In the component project (vue-image-lightbox) I ran

1. npm run build
2. yalc publish

My understanding is that this places my vue-image-lightbox into the yalc store.

Next, I went to my dependent project and ran

1. npm uninstall vue-image-lightbox (remove the existing component)
2. yalc add vue-image-lightbox.  This creates
   a) .yalc directory with the deployed component
   b) adds entry to package.json : "vue-image-lightbox": "file:.yalc/vue-image-lightbox",
3. run npm install to pick up any dependencies

After this I ran my app and went to the component that uses vue-image-lightbox.  In the console I not get the warning

"[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option."

All of the registration code works without issue with the git installed component.  I don't understand why I see this when I try to use yalc.

The component is registered locally with

1. import LightBox from 'vue-image-lightbox'
2. components: { LightBox }

I would love to know what is different about the yalc installed component that is causing this issue.  Is there a better way to test out patches on third party components other than yalc?

### Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `npm run dev` from within your local `vue-image-lightbox` directory? in the `package.json` the main file is `"main": "dist/vue-image-lightbox.min.js",` which would require that you have `built` that project locally. maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Worth a try but still no joy.